# BP Constant in index.php

Tags: index.php

I'm looking through index.php in the root directory of Magento and there is a Constant name BP which is defined in app/autoload.php. I can't see how index.php can see this Constant as there is no link between index.php or app/autoload.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a link. If you see index.php there is a line

> require **DIR** . '/app/bootstrap.php';

and in bootstrap.php there is a line

> require_once **DIR** . '/autoload.php';

so ultimately autoload.php is included.

Hope it helps to clarify your query.
Thanks

Comment: I can see it now. I was getting confused between the Bootstrap.php class in magento/vendor/framework/App and bootstrap.php you have pointed out.